# POSIX Threads/Signals: Portable way to determine to which thread a signal was delivered?

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, signals

I've got a multithreaded server (using POSIX threads), with one thread for each persistent connection.  In one of the threads the other end of the connection closes, resulting in a SIGPIPE being delivered.  Is there a (preferably portable) to determine which thread (and so which connection) this happened for so I can have my signal handler either do the thread/connection cleanup work itself or set a flag so that the main and worker thread respectively see that they need to do it later?

EDIT: I'm wondering if I could perhaps use &errno, store it in a global array and associate it with the server's identifier for the thread, and then search for &errno in the signal handler.  Would the thread's specific errno be visible to the signal handler?  Is my understanding of how the threadsafe errno works even in the ballpark?

Comment: If a signal was delivered to a particular thread then that thread will handle the signal. That's what delivering a signal to a specific thread means. I don't understand what there is to check?

Comment: Because that doesn't tell me which specific thread it was.

Comment: I don't understand, the thread is the thread handling the signal. What information about the current thread do you need to know?

Comment: why do you care about the thread and not the socket itself?

Comment: For one, I need to be able to tell the main thread that it can free its data regarding the connection-handling thread.  In order to do that, the main thread needs to know which particular connection (and so index into its array of connection/thread information) is terminating.  In order to do this, the signal handler needs to know whether it was called from "Connection thread 28" or "Connection thread 91" so it can tell the main thread "Do your cleanup for #28" or "Do your cleanup for #91."  I'm trying to figure out how to get this information from within the signal handler so it can be sent.

Comment: I've found anecdotal evidence that `pthread_self` is safe to use inside a signal handler on many systems, I'm still searching for a definitive reference.

Comment: Perhaps.  But there's still the problem of whether or not the SIGPIPE will actually be sent to the thread associated with the connection that was closed, since my understanding is that the kernel sends it to any thread that doesn't have it blocked.  If I direct all signals to a single thread, on the other hand, it appears that there is no association at all between the signal and the particular socket/handler thread causing it.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify your question title. At the moment it says that you want to determine to which thread a signal was delivered, but it sounds like you don't think that the answer to that question actually helps you solve your problem.

Comment: @bestsss is right - you shold not be managing the connections by thread here, but by socket.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't been clear enough (that's known to happen).  There is a one-to-one correspondence between worker thread and connection socket.  If I know which thread caused the SIGPIPE to be raised, then I know which socket it was on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think so, no.  A better solution for multithreaded servers is to suppress the `SIGPIPE` signal (by calling `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)` as part of the program's startup routine) and then have the thread deal with the error value (-1/EPIPE) returned by `send()` instead.

Signals and multithreading don't mix well.

Comment: I had considered that possibility; the problem is that then I won't detect the disconnection until the next time I need to send data down that connection--which potentially might be never.

Comment: This could easily be caught by selecting on that fd for error only

Comment: Mmm, you're right.  I'm using epoll, and forgot about EPOLLHUP.

Comment: I think you'll find that the "won't detect the disconnection until the next time I need to send data down that connection" issue is a separate problem, and you'll have to deal with it whether you use signals or not.  TCP by default won't detect that an idle connection has been severed for a long time (if ever), depending on the settings of the host's TCP keepalive options.  On some OS's (e.g. Linux) you can set the keepalive options on a per-socket basis (via setsockopt(fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE), while on others (Windows) it's a single global setting.

Comment: ... of course under any OS you can avoid the problem by manually sending a little bit of dummy data every so often on any otherwise-idle TCP connection, just to exercise the TCP connection.  If the remote peer fails to acknowledge the dummy data within a short period (several minutes) you'll get an error then.

Comment: This is right - *all* network servers, not just multithreaded ones, should be ignoring `SIGPIPE` and dealing with `EPIPE` instead.  @SteelyDan: `SIGPIPE` won't be delivered any more promptly than `EPIPE` - the signal is only generated at exactly the same time that an `EPIPE` return would otherwise happen.

Comment: Alright, thank you.  So if I just mask SIGPIPE I should be good; I think this is the route I'll take.  I appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`pthread_self`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_self.html) safely in a signal handler.  It is [async-signal-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03).

This answer is for posterity.  I don't recommend this approach technically.  The other answers and comments, suggesting a different approach, would be better to implement.

At the time this question was posed, the safety of `pthread_self` wasn't necessarily obvious.  The POSIX:2008 Technical Corrigendum 1, dated 2013 (two years after this question was asked), clarifies that `pthread_self` is explicitly async-signal-safe, as noted in the [Linux *signal(7)* man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Relatedly, you mentioned in comments that you weren't sure if the *"kernel sends [a SIGPIPE] to any thread that doesn't have it blocked"*.  That's a good concern — is it a process-directed signal or a thread-directed signal? — and, thankfully, misplaced.  A kernel-generated SIGPIPE is a "synchronously generated" signal in response to some I/O call, and sent to the calling thread.  This was explicitly clarified in Corrigendum 2 (2004) to POSIX:2001 to say that a SIGPIPE in response to a `write` is [*"sent to the **thread**"*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html#tag_16_685_13) (emphasis added).

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to have the signal handler for SIGPIPE just write its thread ID to a global variable and use some other mechanism to signal this to the thread, that should handle it.

Comment: Well, that still raises the same fundamental question of what portable, signal-safe way I have to find out what particular thread this happened in, since I have to figure out what the thread ID is.

Comment: THis is quite easy: e.g. raise an event via whatever event mechanism your system supports (this includes sending something to a pipe) and have a thread listen to these events (which includes selecting on that pipe), read the (lock protected) global variable if necessary, and work on it

Comment: I think a problem with the global-variable approach is what happens if two signals are raised in quick succession -- the second signal could overwrite the value written by the first signal before the first handler executed.  You'd need a lock-protected FIFO queue at least... but then you run into the second problem, which is that you're not allowed to lock a mutex from inside a signal handler.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting.  Are you saying the signal handler sends something to the event-management thread, and then by looking at (say) what particular pipe it was received on the event-management thread knows what thread the event notification came from?

I had considered an essentially similar architecture for that, but shied away from it because it would require three file descriptors per connection (one for the socket plus two for either end of the pipe), which would run up against the limit rather more quickly than I'd like.

(directed at Eugen Rieck)

Comment: @SteelyDan depending of what your definition of "portable" is, there might or not be much simpler ways. The most portable one being the pipe, but you do realize, that you don't need to be connected to that all the time - just connect after receiving the signal!

Comment: I suppose that would work with named pipes: the main thread keeps one end open all the time and polls on it, and then the worker thread only opens up the other end when it needs to.  Though keeping malicious (or poorly-thought-out) outside programs (or other users) from accessing it becomes important in that case.

I had only been thinking in terms of pipe(2) pipes up until now.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a global variable (declared thread-local) to store the thread-id, initialise it on thread creation and refer to it in the thread's signal handler.

For GCC details on this please see here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Thread_002dLocal.html or more general here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage

Comment: The thread-local storage functions aren't signal-safe, as I understand it.

Comment: @Steely Dan: I was not referring to thread-specific data using functions to access it. Please see the reference I just added to my post, for what I was referring to instead.